# Instant File Initalisation - is it enabled for local system accounts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server that is running under local NT service accounts.

[image]

Would file initialisation be enabled given the settings below? Is there an easy way to tell without needing to perform full demo scripts.

[image]

I tried the below from mssqltips but it doesn't contain that column in SQL 2014

```
SELECT  @@SERVERNAME AS [Server Name] ,
        RIGHT(@@version, LEN(@@version) - 3 - CHARINDEX(' ON ', @@VERSION)) AS [OS Info] ,
        LEFT(@@VERSION, CHARINDEX('-', @@VERSION) - 2) + ' '
        + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS NVARCHAR(300)) AS [SQL Server Version] ,
        service_account ,
        instant_file_initialization_enabled
FROM    sys.dm_server_services
WHERE   servicename LIKE 'SQL Server (%'
```

Comment: To check whether Instant File Initalisation works you can create an empty database and then change its MDF file size to several GBs (not log file LDF). If this operation takes only few seconds, then Instant File Initalisation works.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov : how is that faster than running "exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Database Instant File Initialization'" ?

Comment: @MitchWheat, it is not faster, but it is a direct verification that it actually works, rather than reading some flag. Besides, on my SQL Server Express 2008 R2 that query doesn't return anything. The only message it returns is `(0 row(s) affected)`. It looks like your method is indeed for 2012+

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov: That's because " SQL Server (Starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x) SP4,.." as I stated in my answer. No one has mentioned SQL Server 2008....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Database Instant File Initialization'
```

It returns a clear message as to the status of IFI:  i.e. if it's disabled it returns

`"Database Instant File Initialization: disabled...."`

How to turn it on: [Instant File Initialization](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/instant-file-initialization/)

BTW: according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-server-services-transact-sql) the column `instant_file_initialization_enabled` is present in

> "SQL Server (Starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x) SP4, and SQL Server
>   2016 (13.x) SP1 through SQL Server 2017)."

but it wouldn't be the first time the SQL Server Docs are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks very much. It returns "Database Instant File Initialization: disabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required."